# Problema bindValue y valores NULL

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo una función como la que sigue:

```
function xxx( $sql, $params ) {

    $query = $this->con->prepare( $sql );
    $num = count( $params );

    $pos = 0;
    for ( $i=1; $i <= $num; $i++ ) { 

        $param = $params[ $pos ];
        echo( "Parámetro " . $i . " -> " . $param . "<br>" ); //traza
        $query->bindValue( $i, $param ); //$query->bindParam( 1, $param )

        $pos++;
    }

    $query->execute( $params );

    // ...
}
```

Donde unos parámetros posibles podrían ser:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mi_tabla VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)";
$params = [ "Foo", NULL ];
```

Para insertar un nuevo registro en una tabla con los campos: `id, nombre y edad`.

**Para la `edad` se espera un entero, pero también acepta valores nulos**, el problema viene cuando se pasa un valor `NULL`, como parámetro, que no hace el bindeo. No sale ningun error, simplemente no se crea el registro.

He probado a indicar el tipo de parámetro como tipo entero `(PDO::PARAM_INT)` y tipo `NULL (PDO::PARAM_NULL)`, cuando el parámetro es `NULL`, pero sin resultado.

Esta es la configuración para la conexión:

```
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE   => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES     => FALSE, //Inactives emulated prepares
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND   => "SET NAMES utf8"
];
$options[] = ( $this->env === ( 'dev' || 'test' ))
    ? array( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
    : array( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );

try {
    return new \PDO( 
        'mysql:host=' . $db_host . 
        ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, 
        $this->db_user, 
        $this->db_pass, 
        $options 
    );

//...
```

<sub>**Nota**: este ejemplo esta simplificado, la función debe aceptar sentencias diversas con distintos grupos de parámetros.</sub>

Comment: Creo que en tu caso se presenta una situación interesante... pero no estoy seguro. Para confirmarlo, quisiera saber si, al conectar a PDO estás estableciendo la emulación de consultas preparadas a `FALSE`, haciendo algo como esto en la parte donde creas tu objeto PDO (conexión a la db): `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
` Es algo muy importante y que ignoramos en una gran mayoría de casos. Si no lo estás haciendo así, **debes hacerlo** y a partir de ahí te debería funcionar el binding en caso de nulos, y creo que hasta lo hace automáticamente. Espero me confirmes.

Comment: @A. Cedano he añadido los detalles de la conexión en la propia pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una solución.

Cuando el parámetro que se va a insertar, en un campo que acepta un INT o NULL, es NULL, lo convierto a string. Luego es necesario utilizar la norma de validación para el tipo NULL, es decir que la función original quedaría así:

```
function xxx( $sql, $params ) {

foreach ( $params as $key => $value ) {

    if ( is_null( $value ))
        $params[ $key ] = "NULL";
}

$query = $this->con->prepare( $sql );
$num = count( $params );

$pos = 0;
for ( $i=1; $i <= $num; $i++ ) { 

    $param = $params[ $pos ];

    $validation = FALSE;
    if ( is_null( $param ) || $param == "NULL" )
        $validation = \PDO::PARAM_NULL; 

    $query->bindValue( $i, $param, $validation );

    $pos++;
}

$query->execute( $params );

// ...
}
```

La otra opción que tenía planteada era enviar como parámetros a una segunda función zzz(), al comienzo de xxx(), los recibidos por esta y proceder a sustituir en la sentencia los interrogantes directamente por NULL, como parte del string, y eliminar a su vez, los valores NULL del array de $params.

Comment: Si pasas el parámetro nulo como `NULL` sin las comillas y la columna acepta nulos los insertaría correctamente, como he explicado en el punto **(A)** de mi respuesta. Lo he probado en una tabla de prueba de mi bd y funciona, aunque usando mi propia clase PDO... pero es un funcionamiento básico de PDO, por lo que no estás obligado a usar la clase, aunque si quieres puedes usarla :) ... Lo que sí sería necesario desde mi punto de vista es tener una función de validación para que asigne `NULL`  **sin comillas** a aquellos parámetros que no tengan valores.

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu situación con la siguiente clase, [PHP-PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO), que estoy creado yo mismo y me funciona de la siguiente manera:

**A. Si pones `NULL` sin comillas en el array**

```
$datos=$mipdo->query(
                   "INSERT INTO tabla_prueba (columna1, columna2) 
                    VALUES (:val1, :val2)",
                    array("val1"=>"156","val2"=>NULL)
                  );
```

En este caso me inserta `NULL` en la colmuna2.

---

**B. Si pones `NULL` con comillas en el array**

En ese caso NULL es una cadena cualquiera. Entonces el binding lo convierte automáticamente a cero `0`.

Con este código:

```
$datos=$mipdo->query(
                   "INSERT INTO tabla_prueba (columna1, columna2) 
                    VALUES (:val1, :val2)",
                    array("val1"=>"157","val2"=>"NULL")
                  );
```

Me inserta el valor `0`en la `columna2`.

---

**¿Y... cómo lo hace?**

Este es el código que valida los bindings dentro de la clase citada más arriba:

```
        # Asignar parámetros
        if (!empty($this->parametros)) {
            foreach ($this->parametros as $param => $value) {
                if(is_int($value[1])) {
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                } else if(is_bool($value[1])) {
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                } else if(is_null($value[1])) {
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                } else {
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
```

De lo que se deduce que, en efecto, PDO tiene la capacidad de convertir los parámetros, en este caso asignando `0` a un valor que pasamos como cadena.

Yo, de todos modos, no daría esa libertad a PDO, no me gusta delegar en la introducción de mis datos, así que, antes de hacer el binding validaría los datos de alguna manera, y si hubiese la posibilidad de nulos, **los pasaría únicamente como se indica en (A)**, ya que, como sabemos, `NULL` y `0` no son la misma cosa.

**También se podría**, si se quiere, modificar la forma en que la clase valida los bindings, y diciéndole que si es una cadena vacía que, en vez de bindearlo como `STRING` haga el binding como `NULL`, pero eso sería ya algo personal, que dependerá de cada uno y de cómo estén organizados los datos. Insisto de nuevo en que lo mejor es **validar antes de pasar los parámetros**.